# Custom nice URL in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have URL like `mywebsite.com/media/cards/?name=something` and I want to make nice URL for it like `mywebsite.com/media/cards/something`? How can I do that?

I've tried normal htaccess rewrite and wordpress `add_rewrite_rule`. None of it works.

My example:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    $rule = '^media/cards/(.*)/';
    $write = 'media/cards/?name=$matches[1]';
    add_rewrite_rule($rule, $write, 'top');
}
add_action( 'custom', 'custom_rewrite_rule' );
```

Comment: Im not sure about the contents of the function that you created but the `add_action( 'custom'` should be `add_action( 'init'` because the action custom doesn't exist unless you defined it yourself ofcourse.

Comment: @Wilco you are right. I should go with `init`. Although now it shows me always content from `media/cards/` and not for example `media/cards/something`
But there is some progress :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem was solved. First of all I should use `init` not `custom`.
And second I need to register URL param like this:

```
function register_card_param() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%cards%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'register_card_param');
```

Now it works like a charm!